# No internet access on Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 after update

Tags: networking, server

I have an Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 LTS which was running fine until a few hours ago.
In order to update the machine to 16.04.3 LTS, I executed the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

After a reboot of my machine, I see that I'm running 14.04.5 LTS right now, so I'm ready to execute the `do-release-upgrade` command, however, my server is not having internet access however it was working before.

Thus, pinging to either an IP or a URL does not return any results.
I haven't touched the configuration of the network.

This is the output from `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.20.2.132
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.20.2.0
    broadcast 10.20.2.255
    gateway 10.20.2.254
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 10.20.2.1 10.20.2.3
```

What is wrong and how can I solve this?

Comment: Please remove the broadcast and network lines and then do: `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0` Are there any clues as to why it didn't connect?

Comment: I'll try tomorrow since I don't have access to the machine right now. Any idea why it was working before the upgrade?

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution provided did not work. Any other clues why it might not be working?

Comment: The addition of the -v for verbose was intended to produce useful output as to why you didn't connect. Were there *no* useful clues?? Please also edit your question to add the result of: `ifconfig`.